# Add Function Within Variable String

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I am trying to add a function within string to show the output of function via shortcode but it is showing error.

```
function foo_shortcode($atts, $content = null) { 

$datashortcode = '<div>'

.if(function_exists('rtb_kk'))
{
    rtb_kk();
}. 
'</div>'
;

return $datashortcode; 
}

add_shortcode('showfoo', 'foo_shortcode');
```

Where i am making mistake?

Comment: You simply cannot do that. This is syntax error.

Comment: so much syntax errors, first read some tutorial about PHP then write a plugin to wordpress :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax error,

```
$datashortcode = '<div>'.(function_exists('rtb_kk') ? rtb_kk() : '').'</div>';
```

Replace this line.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, It worked but now it is showing shortcode content at the top of the page.

Comment: So fix its position as per your requirement,. Because you haven't shown any html in your question